# Getting result of executed shell command fails/hangs

Tags: android, shell, iostream

I  try to execute shell commands, this does work as it should. Even the result comes back (as is see on LogCat). The problem ist the last line of the result. Every time a readLine() on the last line occurs (which shouldn't occur, temp should be null), the app hangs forever and doesn't come back from the readLine call. Maybe you find the error. I tried readUTF and standart read(), all the same problem. And yes, the app got su-rights.

```
try
                {
                    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
                    DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(process.getOutputStream());
                    DataInputStream osRes = new DataInputStream(process.getInputStream());
                    for (String single : commands) {
                       os.writeBytes(single + "\n");
                       os.flush();
                       String temp = new String();
                       while(  (temp = osRes.readLine()) != null)
                       {                                      
                           Log.v("NITRO", temp);
                           result2 += temp + "\n";                            
                       }                      
                    }
                    os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                    os.flush();
                    process.waitFor();
                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                } catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                }
```

That is the StackTrace where it hangs when i stop debugger when hanging:

```
OSFileSystem.readImpl(int, byte[], int, int) line: not available [native method]    
OSFileSystem.read(int, byte[], int, int) line: 118  
ProcessManager$ProcessInputStream(FileInputStream).read(byte[], int, int) line: 312 
ProcessManager$ProcessInputStream(FileInputStream).read() line: 250 
DataInputStream.readLine() line: 309    
Main$2$1.run() line: 84 
ViewRoot(Handler).handleCallback(Message) line: 587 
ViewRoot(Handler).dispatchMessage(Message) line: 92 
Looper.loop() line: 123 
ActivityThread.main(String[]) line: 4627    
Method.invokeNative(Object, Object[], Class, Class[], Class, int, boolean) line: not available [native method]  
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: 521  
ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run() line: 868  
ZygoteInit.main(String[]) line: 626 
NativeStart.main(String[]) line: not available [native method]
```

Comment: a shot in the dark here, try moving the `exit` before the `while` loop?

Comment: You should address your reply to @st0le or it might never be seen.

Comment: @st0le you are right, that worked, thanks. grabbed that from an example, there the exit was after that commands. But i just want to execute one command, so this should work. You can post it as answer, that i can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try moving the exit before the while loop...You're application never terminates, hence the `while` loop never ends....Moving the `exit` should cause the application to terminate which should cause the loop to get a `null`...